# Sensitivity Approximation - Crank Nicolson

Tags: option-pricing, numerical-methods, european-options, black-scholes-pde, sensitivities

I am looking into a new method of calculating sensitivities starting off with a proof of concept with Black Scholes PDE. Suppose I want to calculate Rho and take the derivative of the PDE (heresy!!) and end up with a new PDE wrt to the interest rate.

[image]

I wish to approximate the above PDE using Crank Nicolson. However I would like to know whether it is possible to create a central difference approximation of:

[image]

Any ideas would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please see below:

[image]

Copied from Quantitative Methods in Derivative Pricing by Tavella.